# how to activate a workook after copying from the first workbook

Tags: excel, vba

in the main workbook I start a button that opens the second workbook, then go back to first workbook, copy a range of  cells, then go to the second workbook (here it goes wrong) to paste

```
Sub Knop7_Klikken()
    Dim TelStaat As Workbook
    Dim Staat As Worksheet
    Dim WicamStaat As Workbook
    Dim Invoer As Worksheet
    Dim Pathname As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Value1 As String

    'TelStaat = "Calculatie 2014 Nesting Wicam.xlsm"

    Set TelStaat = ThisWorkbook

    Value1 = "AN"
    Pathname = "V:\\2013 Calculatie\"
    Filename = "VPT.xlsm"

    'when I use this it wil not open second macro
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Pathname & Filename
    Worksheets("Invoer").Activate
    TelStaat.Activate
    Worksheets("Staat").Columns(3).Find(Value1).Select

    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 6).Select
    Selection.Resize(, 6).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'here it goes wrong,
    Set WicamStaat = ActiveWorkbook
    Worksheets("Invoer").Activate

    Range("A32").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.Calculation = True / xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: In what way does it go wrong? Does it throw an error? If so what error?

Comment: it starts to run the workbook() open marco  from the wicamstaat, the second workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows("copyfromfile.xlsx").Activate 'Copy
Columns("A:H").Select 
Selection.Copy 

Windows("pastetofile.xlsx").Activate 'Paste 
Columns("A:A").Select 
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Comment: kudos to understanding the question. Please add better comments though.